# Access runtime error 3265 Item not found in this collection

Tags: ms-access

old retired guy with passion for databases (Access 2016)
Please help with error.  Have tried in vain to find solution.
Thanks to all who responded.

Please see "new" edited code below.
Thanks to everyone for your comments.

I am updating the code basis comments received and new info learned from other StackOverFlow post.  But, I continue to have issues with making an error handling routing work?

```
'====This Code works Ok:
'................Except: for Error Handler???????
'================================================
Private Sub comBut_CatTotals_Click()
 On Error GoTo EH

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim lonCatID() As Long
    Dim lonCatTot() As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Dim iValue As Long
    Dim tValue As Long

    strSQL = "SELECT " & " qry_EventCategoryTotals_VBA_subquery.[CategoryName], Sum(tblWinnersItems.[Amount]) AS " & "CategoryTotals" & _
             " FROM " & " qry_EventCategoryTotals_VBA_subquery" & _
             " RIGHT " & " JOIN " & " tblWinnersItems" & " ON " & " qry_EventCategoryTotals_VBA_subquery.[ItemID] = tblWinnersItems.[ItemID] " & _
             "GROUP" & " BY " & "qry_EventCategoryTotals_VBA_subquery.[CategoryName];"

        'Debug.Print "strSQL: " & strSQL
        'MsgBox strSQL

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()



            rst.MoveLast

                If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then
                    MsgBox "No Winners recorded...Exiting", vbInformation
                        Exit Sub
                End If

                MsgBox "Number of records:     " & rst.RecordCount
                'intSize = rst.RecordCount
            rst.MoveFirst
                                '... 6 ... records are shown ...

          With rst

            ReDim Preserve lonCatID(rst.RecordCount, 2)
            ReDim Preserve lonCatTot(rst.RecordCount, 2)

                Do While Not rst.EOF


                            i = 0

                        For i = i + 1 To rst.RecordCount - 1


                      lonCatID(1, 1) = rst.Fields(0)

                            iValue = lonCatID(1, 1)

                        Next i


                           t = 0

                        For t = t + 1 To rst.RecordCount - 1


                      lonCatTot(1, 2) = rst.Fields(1)

                            tValue = lonCatTot(1, 2)

                        Next t



                rst.MoveNext

                     MsgBox " CategoryID =   " & iValue & "     Catagory Total =    " & tValue, vbInformation, "Category Totals"
             Loop

       End With

             MsgBox "Loop_Finished"  '.....finishes OK


    db.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    Exit Sub
EH:
If Err.Number = 3021 Then

    MsgBox "No Winners Entered...exiting", vbInformation

End If

MsgBox _
        "There was an Error!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
        "Descriptionis: " & Err.Description, _
        vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
        "Error!"
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: How many fields in the recordset?  `Debug.Print rst.Fields.Count`

Comment: FWIW `rst` may be omitted inside the `With` block (though, this isn't the cause of your error).

Comment: Are you populating fields/controls on form? Use form qualifier: `Me.LiveAuction`, etc., although also not cause of error.

Comment: You indicate that you have 6 records and in your code you are trying to access 6 different fields. Are you sure you are using the recordset properly? If you want to get the next record you need to `rst.MoveNext`. Enumerating over fields means you are accessing a different column on the SAME record/row. Error 3265 happens precisely because the column/field does not exist.

Comment: Edit question to show sample source data.

Comment: Double-check the names of the fields in that recordset.  Access would only complain *"Item not found in this collection"* at `LiveAuction = rst![LiveAuction]` if `rst` does **not** contain a field named `LiveAuction`

Comment: @hisoka, Yes. Thanks.  Finally have begun to understand "records" vs "Fields"  Revised code works except for ErrorHandler.